# Editing posts: where is the link?

Tags: soporte

I wonder if anyone is experiencing the same as me. I can't edit posts anymore, not even in the review section! I can't see the `edit` link.

[image]

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some possible answers on meta.stackoverflow.com, check [Missing edit links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84671/missing-edit-link)

For ease of reference, I'll quote it:

> 1. You are not logged on and the post is 12 hours old or less
> 2. There is already a pending edit on this post
> 3. The [queue is full](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue), only happens rarely on new SE sites with no moderators
> 4. You have been banned for a week cause you submitted many rejected edits

Comment: There are currently no pending suggested edits, so it's not #2 or #3.

Comment: I think I was banned. I can see the link now :) ... Maybe I just suck at editing :(